# H bridge working with led but not with electric motor

Tags: transistors, led, batteries, motor, h-bridge

Noob here. I am trying to make a car which i can control remotely from the internet (ie. lan). I have a H-bridge circuit which has all NPN transistors (bc 547B and datasheet here: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/410427.pdf). Here is the schematic for my circuit: https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/FDG/I6CS/HXVI3O2P/FDGI6CSHXVI3O2P.jpg?auto=webp&frame=1&fit=bounds (original tutorial here: https://www.instructables.com/BUILD-YOUR-OWN-H-BRIDGE-CIRCUIT-USING-NPN-TRANSIST/) except replace the tip transistors with the one i mentioned and for the resistor i used 1k ohm resistors and also i wasn't able to get the transistors working with a shared supply thiny (i had to put a resistor before each transistor because for some whatever reason it won't work if i share the base voltage from one resistor which may hint at what i am doing wrong). The circuit works as expected with 15 volt input voltage for the led (9v battery and 4 x 1.5 AA battery pack in series), but when i connect the electric motor, the motor wont spin. (the motor is this: http://www.mootio-components.com/motor-current-dc-voltage-150v-rpm-9000rpm-fa-130-ra-2270_refe_003836-1.5.html) Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: _"The circuit works as expected with 15 volt input voltage for the led (9v battery and 4 x 1.5 AA battery pack in series)"_ - The motor is rated for 1.5V. What power source are you using with it?

Comment: _”I have a H-bridge circuit which has all NPN transistors”_ Schematic > words. You can use the built in schematic tool by clicking on edit and then the schematic symbol.

Comment: Your 9V battery may not be able to supply enough current to overcome the startup inertia.  Try it with nothing but ALKALINE AA's, probably will work much better.  You can easily prove whether I'm right or not by just connecting the motor directly across your existing supply.     The LED doesn't have that problem, it doesn't have inertia

Comment: Did you think the motor was rated for 15V? Perhaps you should swap it for a higher voltage lower current version, lkike this:- http://www.mootio-components.com/motor-current-dc-voltage-900v-rpm-4800rpm-fk-260-sa-10400_refe_000213-9.html

Comment: Please post a schematic of your specific setup. The instructable that you linked has it's own problems... your question should stay focused on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, everything is wrong.  Sorry.

**The Transistors**

The TIP122 is an old-school, power, *Darlington* transistor.  The power part means it won't fry trying to conduct the current the motor "wants" (it's rated up to one amp, your BC547 parts are rated at 0.1A continuously).  The Darlington part means that it doesn't take much base current -- and you need that if you're going to drive the thing from a microcontroller.

**The Schematic**

If you look at the picture, it's easy to count three base resistors, and there's another one hiding behind the left transistor in the foreground.  With the two resistors shown in the schematic, the transistor connected to ground "shorts out" the signal to the transistor connected to power -- so your upper transistor will never come on, or will only come on weakly.

**The Supply Voltage**

The motor is designed for 1.5V, so there's no point in using a voltage that's much greater than 1.5V plus the drop in your circuit.  If you modify your circuit to match what's pictured, the high-side transistors will act as emitter-followers, and will run at your microcontroller's output voltage minus their base-emitter drop.  For the TIP122 that's 1.5V (because they're Darlingtons).  For a "plain old" silicon NPN that's more like 0.7V -- except such transistors need more base drive for the same collector (and emitter) current; you don't have that much drive available.

So -- find yourself some Darlington transistors that are capable of driving 1A collector current, use about 5V for VCC, *use this schematic*, and you should at least be able to turn the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqwR0R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>